# Cant get from the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a main activity with one container where I want to display four fragments. This main activity have a bottom bar that should inflate diferent fragments when I press one specific tab. I am trying to use backstack calls to turn my app more fluid. The code bellow shows the listenners for that bottom bar

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

    if (tabId == R.id.tab_people) {
        cretePeopleFrgament();
    }  else if (...) {
                ...
     }

    bottomBar.setOnTabReselectListener(new OnTabReselectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabReSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            if (tabId == R.id.tab_people) {
                cretePeopleFrgament();
            } else if (...) {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I start my fragment like that

```
void creteProfileFrgament() {
        ...    
        Fragment fraggy = new FragmentProfile();
        replaceFragment(fraggy,"Profile",null);

    }
```

So with the next method I am trying if the fragment that I want to inflate is already on the backstack, if it is he should be poped and not created. And what is happening is that always generate the fragments passing from the onStart when I want pop from backstack. From my debbug I already see that he correctly added, the boolean fragmentpop cames true but its not poped

```
private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment, String name,Bundle bundle){
    boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(name,0);
if (!fragmentPopped){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
    FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(name);
    ft.replace(R.id.conteiner, fragment);
    if(bundle!=null)
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.commit();
}

}
```

The objective of this is work with the onBackPressed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        bottomBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int index = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
        String tag;
        if(index==-1) {
            tag = "default";
        }else {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(index);
            tag = backEntry.getName();
        }
        switch (tag){
            case "Profile":
                bottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(0);
                break;
            case "People":
                bottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(1);
                break;
            case "default":
                bottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(0);
        }

    }
```

A lot of thanks

Comment: Try editing your question and rephrase some words and title properly

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a new Fragment every time,if you want to pop from the backstack ,you should retain it without creating it again...

look into your creteProfileFrgament mehtod.

Comment: So when I create a new Fragment it starts on onStart method?  And how can I fix my problem ? thanks

Comment: fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("name");
later when you need it : 
FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack ("name", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);